# Reason of using diode between common mode choke legs

Tags: power-supply, diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, emi-filtering

I'm investigating SMPS circuits. And I couldn't understand why there is a diode beetween common mode choke legs (I don't know exactly but it seems like signal diode) What is the main reason of using diode on there ?

[image]

Circuit guess

[image]

Bottom side
[image]

Full photo
[image]

Comment: @Justme I added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a gas discharge tube (GDT) in a glass package.

In some power supplies they are shunting one of the common mode choke coils, so this is not an unique design.

It makes somewhat sense that it seems to shunt high voltage transients so that they bypass the common mode choke neutral coil.

Comment: I thought gas discharge tubes were always way larger than that.

Answer (score 3):

My speculative answer:

You wouldn't put a unidirectional device across an input CM winding for clamp suppression. It would conduct every half-cycle, after all. A bidirectional TVS or a gas-tube would work for clamping - in both cases, should sufficient voltage be present to cause breakdown, the TVS or gas tube would clamp the voltage. (This sort of event is usually only induced by lightning strikes or related input disturbances.)

Clearly the part that is stuffed in that position isn't a diode - it looks more like a resistor to me. I would argue that:

1. The device was originally designed with a TVS for surge clamping. For whatever reason they used a polarized diode PCB footprint for the TVS.
2. Later testing found that a passive damping element (like a resistor) was sufficient to protect the unit from surge damage, so they stuffed a resistor into the diode's location.

EDIT: It may actually be a gas-tube upon closer inspection. (I still don't think it's a diode.)

Comment: A resistor across such devices is common practice to dampen out any associated oscillations

Comment: I've never seen a resistor in that package before.  Can you provide a link to an example?  I'm sure it has special properties to be in "glass" like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a [Flyback Diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode). When the circuit is turned off after reaching a steady-state, The coil has back EMF which is reversed in polarity. This will result in high voltage, potentially creating an electric arc. The flyback diode is reverse biased when the circuit has power, but when turned off it provides a path to dissipate power, avoiding an electric arc.

Comment: I would say it results in a high voltage rather than current.  The (now collapsing) EMF tries to keep current going in the original direction, but now that the circuit is open no current can flow.  This creates a potentially high voltage (reverse from normal).  The flyback diode allows current to flow, preventing voltage build up, and allowing the field to collapse.

Comment: I put in an edit with this information if you want to look

Comment: The common mode filter is in the AC part of the circuit, so putting a single-ended diode there would shunt the filter for half of the AC cycle. During normal operation there is flux cancellation so the CM choke doesn't "see" the line current per se. It only presents an impedance to any CM noise.

Comment: @HackerBoss Thank you, I approved your edit, but it may take a bit before it shows up.  When you get higher rep, your edits won't need approval.